# oracle negative look ahead regular expression not working

Tags: sql, regex, database, oracle, regex-lookarounds

I have a regular expression that works well in Java but not in Oracle.

It looks for `<a href="abcd" etc etc xyz >` tag where `xyz` is not in the element block.

```
<a href="abcd" etc etc xyz > = not match
<a href="abcd" etc etc > = match
```

Regx: `(<[a][\s]+[^>]*[href]="[^>](?:(?!xyz).)*?)(>)`

but same thing returns null in Oracle

```
select I from atable
where regexp_like (column, '(<[a][\s]+[^>]*[href]="[^>](?:(?!xyz).)*?)(>)')
```

Any idea?

Let me clarify more on this problem. Actually I need to accomplish this.
Let's say we have a text column 'datacolumn', that contains html syntax data. I need to find string

```
<a href="abcd" etc etc >
```

and replace that with

```
<a href="abcd" etc etc xyz>
```

If there is already  strings in the data column, I shouldn't insert another xyz but simply leave it. So lets say if the column has a data like this

```
<a href="abcd" etc etc > asdf </a> etc etc <a href="efgh" etc etc xyz>
```

then I want to have this replaced as

```
<a href="abcd" etc etc xyz> asdf </a> etc etc <a href="efgh" etc etc xyz>
```

If I don't use negative look ahead I end up inserting double xyz like this

```
<a href="abcd" etc etc xyz> asdf </a> etc etc <a href="efgh" etc etc xyz xyz>
```

I am using

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(datacolunm,'(<[a][\s]+[^>]*[href]="[^>](?:(?!xyz).)*?)(>)')','\1 xyz \3')
```

But as negative lookahead is not supported or my reqex is not oracle compatible, I am not finding any matches. This works in Java though.

Comment: I don't think lookaround assertions are supported in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

There is no documentation on the negative lookahead feature associated with reg expressions in Oracle SQL.

Thus, one uses a decode statement to reproduce the negative lookahead feature here:

```
SELECT
    DECODE(
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(
            REGEXP_SUBSTR( '<a href="abcd" etc etc >', '<a\s[^>]*href="abcd"[^>]*>' ),
            'xyz'
        ),
        'xyz',
        NULL,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR( '<a href="abcd" etc etc >', '<a [^>]*href="abcd"[^>]*>' )
    )
FROM dual;
```

**Explanation**

1. Check to see if we have the "a" element with the href="abcd" attribute 1st with this function:

   `REGEXP_SUBSTR('<a href="abcd" etc etc >','<a\s[^>]*href="abcd"[^>]*>')`
2. Search to see if the string pattern, 'xyz' exists within this element.

   `REGEXP_SUBSTR( calculation 1 ,'xyz')`
3. Decode

   `if 'xyz' exists in element, then NULL otherwise element.`